# Add keys to a dictionary with automatically incremented values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, d, with values 0,1,2 for the 3 keys:

```
{'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2}
```

I want to add 2 new keys from a list and automatically increment their values as 3 and 4

I can get this far

```
newkeys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
d.update([newkeys])
```

gives an updated dictionary, but with no values assigned to the new keys

```
{'-11111': 0,
 'hello kitty': 1,
 'hello this is me': 2,
 'give a dog a bone': 'take a dog for a walk'}
```

what I want is this:

```
{'-11111': 0,
 'hello kitty': 1,
 'hello this is me': 2,
 'give a dog a bone': 3,
 'take a dog for a walk': 4}
```

Is there an efficient and simple way to do this?
thanks

Comment: I didn't realize this was a necro when I posted my answer. Seems a few others did the same. You should accept an answer so that this thread can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this will only work for Python 3.8+. Before 3.8, the `dict` type was not insertion-ordered, and therefore *any* attempt to do what OP wants would be much more of a pain in versions < 3.8.

### A simple solution

Here's a simple solution which doesn't require importing any modules:

```py
{val: idx for idx, val in enumerate([*old_dict, *new_keys])}
```

A quick demo:

```py
>>> old_dict = {'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2}
>>> new_keys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
>>> new_dict = {val: idx for idx, val in enumerate([*old_dict, *new_keys])}
>>> new_dict
{'-11111': 0,
 'hello kitty': 1,
 'hello this is me': 2,
 'give a dog a bone': 3,
 'take a dog for a walk': 4}
```

This requires building a new dictionary, and in addition to other solutions will not account for duplicate keys (e.g., if you add another `"-11111"` to `new_keys`, the old one will be erased, and your count won't be updated).

A nice bonus of using `enumerate()` is that it allows for starting your counter at any value by using the optional `start` parameter:

```py
>>> {val: idx for idx, val in enumerate([*old_dict, *new_keys], -99)}
{'-11111': -99,
 'hello kitty': -98,
 'hello this is me': -97,
 'give a dog a bone': -96,
 'take a dog for a walk': -95}
```

### Alternative solution with optional start and step size

If you want a custom starting value *and* a custom step size:

```py
def new_dict(old_dict, new_keys, start=0, step=1):
    keys = [*old_dict, *new_keys]
    stop = len(keys) * step
    return dict(zip(keys, range(start, stop, step)))
```

Demo:

```py
>>> new_dict(old_dict, new_keys, step=2)
{'-11111': 0,
 'hello kitty': 2,
 'hello this is me': 4,
 'give a dog a bone': 6,
 'take a dog for a walk': 8}

>>> new_dict(old_dict, new_keys, step=3)
{'-11111': 0,
 'hello kitty': 3,
 'hello this is me': 6,
 'give a dog a bone': 9,
 'take a dog for a walk': 12}

>>> new_dict(old_dict, new_keys, start=-4, step=3)
{'-11111': -4,
 'hello kitty': -1,
 'hello this is me': 2,
 'give a dog a bone': 5,
 'take a dog for a walk': 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the list of `newkeys` and set each new key to the length of list of items currently in the `dict`:

```py
d = {'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2}
newkeys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
    newkeys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
    for key in newkeys:
        d[key] = len(d.items())
```

To add new keys, simply use `d[keyname] = keyvalue`, and the key is appended.

Comment: @MichaelK You can keep your `dict.update` logic with a list comprehension. See my answer below.

Comment: Note that this will not work if you have the need to add update keys that already might be present in the dict.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I found a safer, less magical/hacky way of solving the problem than in my original answer

```py
key_id_map = {}

def update_key_id_map(keys):
    for key in keys:
        if key_id_map.get(key) == None:
            key_id_map[key] = len(key_id_map)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> key_id_map
{}
```

```
>>> update_key_id_map([0, 1, 2])
>>> key_id_map
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
```

```
>>> update_key_id_map([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> key_id_map
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
```

```
>>> # Reset to demonstrate original question
>>> key_id_map = {'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2}
```

```
>>> newkeys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
>>> update_key_id_map(newkeys)
>>> key_id_map
{'-11111': 0,
 'hello kitty': 1,
 'hello this is me': 2,
 'give a dog a bone': 3,
 'take a dog for a walk': 4}
```

**Bonus:** Unlike other solutions, this one can tolerate updating the dict with already existing keys. Only the new keys will be taken into account and recieve an incremented ID.

```
>>> update_key_id_map(['hello kitty', 'give a dog a bone', 'an actual new key, the others already exist'])
>>> dict(key_id_map)
{'-11111': 0,
 'hello kitty': 1,
 'hello this is me': 2,
 'give a dog a bone': 3,
 'take a dog for a walk': 4,
 'an actual new key, the others already exist': 5}
```

Interested to hear any feedback.

Comment: Nice! You could even add the dict as a parameter to make this function more global

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. I am unsure why I didn't go that route... I think in my initial code, things were a bit badly architected and I needed the dict in two places, didn't want to hand it through multiple functions.

Comment: Note that if value is None in the current solution, then things fall apart a bit. But then so would having a duplicate int value for example. This dict requires a strict writing to it (only form this function)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to add new keys while incrementing the values based on existing values.

### Solution 1

```py
d = {'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2}
newkeys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
value = max(d.values())
for key in newkeys:
    value = value + 1
    d[key] = value
```

This solution is easy to understand and does not use any external library.

### Solution 2

This solution uses the `itertools.count()` function. This function will generate increasing numbers. For example, `itertools.count(3)` will generate 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...

```py
import itertools

d = {'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2}
newkeys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
values = itertools.count(max(d.values()) + 1)
d.update(zip(newkeys, values))
```

In this solution, `max(d.values())` will give 2, so `values` will generate 3, 4, 5, ... Next, we zip the `newkeys` and `values` and use it to update the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

One other option assuming you don't want to start from 0 (but want to increment)

```
class CustomIncrementer:
    def __init__(self, initial_value_or_dictionary):
        if isinstance(initial_value_or_dictionary, dict):
            # Assumes that the values in the input dictionary are only numerics
            self.my_dict = initial_value_or_dictionary
            self.counter = max(initial_value_or_dictionary.values()) + 1
        else:  # assumes it's a numeric 
            self.my_dict = {}
            self.counter = initial_value_or_dictionary

    def update(self, list_of_words: list):
        for element in list_of_words:
            self.my_dict[element] = self.counter
            self.counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you know exactly what the keys and values should be, why don't you just do:

```
newkeys = [['give a dog a bone', 3], ['take a dog for a walk', 4]]
d.update(newkeys)
```

In each sublist, the first item becomes a key and the second one the associated value.

EDIT:

The same idea, with the incremental feature

```
d = {'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2}
newkeys = ['give a dog a bone', 'take a dog for a walk']
d.update([[x, y + len(d)] for y, x in enumerate(newkeys)])
# {'-11111': 0, 'hello kitty': 1, 'hello this is me': 2,
#  'give a dog a bone': 3, 'take a dog for a walk': 4}
```